# Confusion in Memory Addressing with Arrays

Tags: c++, c, storage, memory-address

Lets have an array of type int:-

```
        int arr[5];
```

Now,

```
       if arr[0] is at address 100 then
       Why do we have;
       arr[1] at address 102 , 
       arr[2] at address 104 and so on.
```

Instead of

```
       arr[1] at address 101 , 
       arr[2] at address 102 and so on.
```

Is it because an integer takes 2 bytes?

Does each memory block has 1 Byte capacity (whether it is 32 bit processor or 64 bit)?

Comment: This is subject to hardware, but surely an `int` is `4 bytes`.

Comment: The question is unclear. Apparently sizeof(int) is 2 for you. Do you expect the integers to overlap in memory in your array to be at 1-byte distance from each other? - A byte is the smallest addressable unit. Each byte has a different address, differing by one.

Comment: @Mr.TAMER: no, this entirely depends on your system.

Comment: This is not the reason, I never pay attention to addresses, but an Int in a PHP array takes 68 bytes. 16 bytes for value structure (zval), 36 bytes for hash bucket, and 2*8 = 16 bytes for memory allocation headers

Comment: Do you mean `arr[2] at address 104`? Because `arr[3] at address 104` does not make any sense.

Comment: @sandbox: Could you explain the thinking behind your second example (`101`/`103`)?

Comment: +1 @Fred.  The numbers presented don't make sense on ANY machine.

Comment: @Mr.TAMER: 16 bits is the minimum size of an `int` per the C standard. The number of bytes in an `int` (i.e. the `sizeof`) depends on the hardware; some embedded systems have 16-bit `char`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first example is consistent with 16-bit `ints`.

As to your second example (`&arr[0]==100`, `&arr[1]==101`, `&arr[2]==103`), this can't possibly be a valid layout since the distance between consecutive elements varies between the first pair and the second.

Comment: That means 1 memory space on my processor can hold 1 byte?

Comment: @sandbox: per definition, yes. The size of a byte various per C implementation, though; it may be 8 or 16 bits.

Answer (score 3):

> It is because an integer takes 2 bytes?

Yes

Apparently on your system, `int` has the size of 2. On other systems, this might not be the case. Usually `int` is either sized 4 or 8 bytes, but other sizes are possible also.

Comment: machines with `int` of 8 bytes are **very** infrequent. The only ones I know of are some Cray under UNICOS.

Comment: On my windows box: `sizeof(int)==sizeof(long)==8`

Comment: which Windows version, which processor and which compiler? Could you check again because there is no implementation I know of on Windows with 8 bytes `int`

Answer (score 0):

You are right, on your machine the sizeof int is 2, so next possible value in the array will be 2 bytes away from the previous one.

```
-------------------------------
|100|101|102|103|104|105|106....
-------------------------------
arr[0]  arr[1]  arr[2]
```

There is no guaranty regarding size of `int`. C++ spec just says that sizeof(int) >= sizeof(char). It depends upon processor, compiler etc.

For more info [try this](http://tsemba.org/c/inttypes.html#int)